# Menu items get added outside of the group

Tags: android, xml, menu

I have a very nice NavigationView with a menu.
This menu consists of two groups, `menu_top` and `menu_bottom`.

Relevant menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/menu_top">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_frontpage"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    </group>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
        android:id="@+id/menu_bottom">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
            android:title="@string/menu_login"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_register"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
            android:title="@string/menu_register" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I try to add multiple items to the `menu_top` group, but this would not work.
It instead adds it below the `menu_bottom` group. You can see this because my logout button is in between two lines, so above this button is a group and below this button is a group.

Relevant Java code:

```
Menu mainMenu = navigationView.getMenu();
        for(PageModel page : pages) {
            MenuItem pageButton = mainMenu.add(R.id.menu_top,Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE,page.title.rendered);
        }
```

Screenshot:
[image: Situation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `android:orderInCategory="999"` for the bottom group.
Code will look like this:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:id="@+id/menu_top">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_frontpage"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
                android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        </group>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single"
            android:id="@+id/menu_bottom"
            android:orderInCategory="999">
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_login"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_secure"
                android:title="@string/menu_login"
                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_register"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_view"
                android:title="@string/menu_register" />
        </group>
    </menu>
```